# Indexes to support OR condition over a JOIN

Tags: postgresql

I'm wondering if Postgres has any support optimizing for following fundamental problem.

I want to do a search a agains two columns on different tables joined via a foreign key. I have created an index for each column. If I do my join query and have a where condition for either one or the other column, the respective index is used to filter the result and the query performance is great. If use two where clause combined by an OR for one field on each table, the query gets very slow and no indexes are used. Presumably this is because the optimizer sees no other way than doing a full table join and scan to resolve. The query looks something like this:

```
select table1.id
from table1
left join table2 on table1.fk = table2.id
where table1.haystack ilike '%needle%' or table2.haystack ilike '%needle%'
```

The operation (ilike) isn't the issue and interchangeable, I have a working Trigram index setup. I just want to find out if there is any other way to make this type of query performant beside denormalizing all searched fields into one table.

I would be very greateful for any ideas.

Comment: Unrelated, but: your WHERE clause effectively turns the outer join back into an inner join

Comment: A basic solution could be do a `UNION ALL` between two queries, each one with a where condition on one column only

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : can you explain why the where clause turns the outer join into an inner join ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no special support in the database to optimize this. Do it yourself:

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
   JOIN table2 ON table1.fk = table2.id
WHERE table1.haystack ILIKE '%needle%'
UNION
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
   JOIN table2 ON table1.fk = table2.id
WHERE table2.haystack ILIKE '%needle%'
```

Provided both conditions are selective and indexed with a trigram index, and you have indexes on the join condition, that will be faster.

Comment: Hey Laurenz, thanks for the answer. We were thinking about using UNION, too. In practice the query we are talking about is actually VERY complex and processing heavy, with a lot of joins, lateral joins, heavy sub-selects etc. And we are not just talking about two joined tables to search in but actually 4. But even given all this UNIONS probably is the way to go if we don't want to do denormalization or an actual search engine. I was just wondering if there is another approach.

Comment: Denormalization is an approach - essentially you would need a materialized view for your complicated query, which comes with its own set of problems.

Comment: I hadn't though about materialized views in that context. While materializing the full query would be impractical for various reasons, I could create a materialized view of of just the searchable columns and then left join it through the main primary key. It's been over a decade since I last used materialized views. Has the "blocking while refreshing" issue been solved? Otherwise one could use two instances of the view and time based alternating access and refresh I guess.

Comment: You can `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` now. But you still would have to live with stale data.